# Clickable area around overlay content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

It's probably an easy solution but I just can't get my head around it. What I want to do is to make an overlay layer with child layers clickable, without assigning any interaction to the children. Like so -

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

jQuery sample function:

```
$('.overlay').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

What happens here is that the function runs even if I click on a child layer. How should I set this up so that only the area around the children is affected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check the click target by `e.target`

```
$('.overlay').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.content')) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, why didn't I think of that... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try with [**e.stopPropagation();**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) -

```
$('.content').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('child');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cDnud/1/)
    ​

Comment: Thanks for the tip about stopPropagation. Wasn't aware of that method.

Answer (score 1):

Created example, click on content prevent hide actions
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/wQVg4/1/)